# Is it possible to export the image from Graph View in Studio?

Tags: orientdb

New to OrientDB and really liking it for my Graph database purposes. The Studio is a nice interface and I enjoy being able to toss results of a query to the Graph View.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to export the Graph view to disk as a .png, .svg, etc.  I've looked in the documentation, but not found any leads.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature now, you can just use print screen.